# How to properly read "obfuscated" cookies sent by client on the server-side

Tags: asp.net, angularjs, cookies, ng-storage

I need to read cookies sent by client on the server-side of my web site.

Client sets cookies via [ngStorage](https://github.com/gsklee/ngStorage) module:

```
$scope.$storage = $localStorage.$default({
    basket: []
});

$scope.addToBasket = function(id) {
    $scope.$storage.basket.push(id);
};
```

And I tried to read it like this in server's controller:

```
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        var basket = Request.Cookies["basket"];
        Console.WriteLine(basket);

        return View();
    }
```

but `Request.Cookies["basket"]` returns `null` because it doesn't have cookies related to that key.

It seems that such libraries like `ngStorage` uses their own "unique" names for cookies like `_ga` instead of the original ones (like `basket` in my example).

How can I read it on the server-side then?

Comment: there are no obfuscated cookies ! what to obfuscated on one line of data

Comment: @Aristos Well, I mean that names of such cookies are "uglified", so we get something like `_ga` instead of `basket`

Comment: @FrozenHeart are you sure that cookies were set properly via ngStorage? It doesn't obfuscate anything...

Comment: @krutkowski86 Well, I'm not sure. I just checked my cookies and didn't find anything that contains "basket" values in it for the `localhost`

Answer (score 0):

[If you wanna use session storage](https://github.com/gsklee/ngStorage#read-and-write--demo) you gotta use `$sessionStorage` instead of `$localStorage`:

```
$scope.$storage = $localStorage.$default({...
```